# How to store a row from a cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to pull a row from a data-filled cursor and store it in another object for other use.

my code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpener.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor dataSet = db.query(WPTemplateDB.PRODUCT_TABLE, 
                                null, //all columns
                                null, //where clause
                                null, //where clause args
                                null, null, null);//groupBy, having, orderBy
while (dataSet.moveToNext()){

                Product product = new Product(dataSet);
                pArray.add(product);
            }
```

my storing object:

```
public Product(Cursor cursor){

        productData = cursor;
    }

    public String getData(String column){
        Log.d(column, productData.getColumnIndex(column)+"");
        return productData.getString(productData.getColumnIndex(column));
    }
```

Now, I am facing an error of "index 10 requested with a size of 10". What can I do to this?

Comment: `moveToNext` will change the data that the cursor points to; you must read all the values out of the cursor in the `Product` constructor. Anyway, in which line do you get the error?

Comment: at the line of return in getData() function

Comment: From where is `getData` called? This does not appear in the code you've shown. And where do you call `dataSet.close()`?

Comment: dataSet.close() is just under the while loop in my code, sorry for not copying that...
and the getData() function is in my object Product :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this answer is inspired from `@cuasodayleo`, I just translate it to be another code.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpener.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor dataSet = db.query(WPTemplateDB.PRODUCT_TABLE, 
                                new String[]{WPTemplateDB.PRODUCT_ID}, 
                                null, //where clause
                                null, //where clause args
                                null, null, null);//groupBy, having, orderBy
            while (dataSet.moveToNext()){

                Product product = new Product(dataSet.getInt(0), db);
                pArray.add(product);
            }
            dataSet.close();
```

The Product object:

```
public Product(int pid, SQLiteDatabase db){

        productData = db.query(WPTemplateDB.PRODUCT_TABLE, 
                null, //all columns
                WPTemplateDB.PRODUCT_ID+"=?", //where clause
                new String[]{pid+""}, //where clause args
                null, null, null);//groupBy, having, orderBy    

    }

    public String getData(String column){       
        Log.d("count", productData.getCount()+"");
        if (productData.getCount()>0){
            Log.d(column, productData.getColumnIndex(column)+"");
            productData.moveToFirst();
            return productData.getString(productData.getColumnIndex(column));
        } else {
            return null;
        }       
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't should using cursor is contructors for `Product` objects. It will leak memory because cursor must close when not use.
You should read data from cursor then send data to contructor `Product` like:

```
String productName = cursor.getString(0);// 0 is column name
......
cursor.close();

Product product = new Product(name);
```

Comment: I know it is one of the method....but I have a lot of columns, so I have to do in this way for convenience for further development. And thanks for your comment :)

Comment: By the way, so u mean that cursor cannot be passed to other objects??

Comment: @Simon: cursor like poiter, so just use it to excute one distance time. Don't keep it on objects.

Answer (score 0):

Indexes are zero-based. It means that is size is 10, max index will be 9. From the code you've posted, everything is fine, so the error in some other place of your code.

Comment: I think the error is from the object Product "getData()" part...but I have no idea with it

Comment: @Simon post entire logcat; `getColumnIndex` will return zero-based index of column or -1 if this column doesn't exist, the problem is not here

Comment: the getColumnIndex returns 1, so I think the program knows the column exists